# compareAndSet in an if statement. Is it an atomic operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

It's clear that [compareAndSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#compareAndSet(boolean,%20boolean)) is an atomic operation. But what about the two following code snippets?

```
if (value.compareAndSet(true, false)) // No negation
```

or like this:

```
if (!value.compareAndSet(true, false)) // There is a negation
```

I think the first operation is atomic (but not quite sure because there is an if), and the second one is definitely not atomic because it consists of compareAndSet and a negation.

Comment: The access to memory is atomic, what you do with it the outcome is usually not considered because it doesn't access memory.  By this logic the use of the `if` also is not atomic.

Comment: @Peter, is there any proof?

Comment: compareAndSet is atomic because the documentation says so.  You can't assume any more code is atomic because there is nothing which says it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code more or less compiles to

```
boolean result = value.compareAndSet(true, false)
if (result){
// or
if (!result){
```

That `result` is a local variable (and moreover a primitive).

There is no way that other threads can get to it and someone "corrupt it".

Of course, the AtomicBoolean itself may have a different value the next time you look at it. But you will still know if your `compareAndSet` was successful.

Comment: As far as I understand, I can use `if (value.compareAndSet(true, false)) { // my logic }` or `boolean result = value.compareAndSet(true, false); if (result) { // my logic }` to guarantee that my logic is executed **once**. Suppose thread 1 updates `value` from its initial value `true` to `false` and runs my logic. When compareAndSet is called on thread 2, `compareAndSet` will return false and my logic won't be executed.

Comment: Thus, according to [Peter's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597591/compareandset-in-an-if-statement-is-it-an-atomic-operation#comment58880622_35597591), `if (!value.compareAndSet(true, false))` is **not atomic**, but it's safe to use your code snippet to ensure something is executed once.